# php random two even numbers with the first a higher value

Tags: php, random

I have the following code that gives out a random math question, i am trying to get only even numbers from the rand tag and make the first number higher than the second number.

```
<?php 
//set the sum
$operarors = array( '+','-');
$operator = $operarors[rand(0,1)];
//random the numbers
$numberone = rand(4,10);
$numbertwo = rand(2,4);
//get the answer
if ($operator == '-') {
$answer1 = $numberone - $numbertwo;
}
if ($operator == '+') {
$answer1 = $numberone + $numbertwo;
}
if ($operator == 'x') {
$answer1 = $numberone * $numbertwo;
}
if ($operator == '/') {
$answer1 = $numberone / $numbertwo;
}

echo "Question: $numberone $operator $numbertwo<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $answer1;

?>
```

i have looked at the [random function](https://php.net/manual/ro/function.rand.php) and can't seem to find the information i need for both problems

To fix the value of the first number to be higher than the second i have told it to random numbers between 4 and 10 and asked for random numbers between 2 and 4 for the second

```
$numberone = rand(4,10);
$numbertwo = rand(2,4);
```

But for the functionality of this code i would like it that i dont need to do this.

The reason behind this is if the first number is 4 and the second is 5 the answer is -1.
this is going to be for my little daughter to help with her maths and there not taught - numbers this early :)

To random even numbers i have came to an end of my thinking as i have tried [google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20random%20even%20numbers) to find the answer to the issue and not finding anything to work on

you proberbly can tell im not an expert in php so please give a little more expernation so i can achieve a better knowledge

Thanks in advance

Comment: To generate a random even number - generate a random number in `[1, N/2]` range then multiply by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a random number that is even do the following:

```
$max = 10;
echo $evenRandomNb = rand(0, round(($max / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)) * 2;
```

To get 2 random numbers with one bigger than the second (never equal) do:

```
$max = 10;
echo $firstNb = rand(0, $max - 1);
echo $secondNb = rand($firstNb + 1, $max);
```

You might want to combine the two methods to get two even numbers, the second one being bigger than the first one:

```
$max = 10;
echo $firstNb = rand(0, round((($max - 1) / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)) * 2;
echo $secondNb = rand(round((($firstNb + 2) / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN), round(($max / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)) * 2;
```

Comment: how would i use both examples? as the last example isnt even numbers. But many thanks for your answer

Comment: Perfect! many thanks i had to use `$secondNb` first for the larger number

Answer (score 0):

Just do `rand()`, then multiply by 2 (guaranteeing an even number), put them in an array, and `arsort()` them (puts them in descending order)

```
$numbers = arsort(array(
    rand(0,5)*2,
    rand(0,5)*2
));    
if($numbers[0] == $numbers[1]) {
    $numbers[1]+=2; // if you need them to be not equal
}

echo 'This is number one: ' . $numbers[0] . '.<br>';
echo 'This is number two: ' . $numbers[1] . '.';
```

Comment: Equality need to be taken into account though.

Comment: `$numbers[1]+=2` --- this may go out of expected range now :-)

Comment: @zerkms - I think my answer gets the main point across about an easy way to get 2 even numbers in descending order.  Any additional stuff should be pretty easily managed.